# AS3 - How can I dispacth an Event.CHANGE from an Array/Vector?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, events, vector

I would like to subclass an `Array` or `Vector` to dispatch and `Event.CHANGE` when any elements value changes.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you could extend EventDispatcher or your could use composition to write a class which extends EventDispatcher and contains the Array/Vector you mention. Still, wouldn't you want other parts of your application sending notification when data has changed, as opposed to the data itself ? (think loose coupling)

Comment: possibly, in this case im storing a lot of colour values in which a lot of tweening action happens. 20 odd values may be rapidly changing a the same time and this way I would be dispatching one event every frame instead of 20

Comment: If you have class A which triggers the change, class B which handles the change for example, updates it's array (20 items) and triggers another single event/signal back to notify the change is done to whomever might be listening and wants to retrieve the updated 20 items from class B, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways of approaching it, if you want to create your own collection:
1) Extend Array class, and use method like updata(index:int, value:*) to update data in it instead of array accessors (myArray[i] = newValue). And in update method you can dispatch change event. This might make your code less concise.

2) Extend Proxy and override setProperty and getProperty methods in flash_proxy namespace. This will allow you to use array access operators ([key]), downside is – Proxy is slow.

There is number of ready open source collections based on proxy out there.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an ArrayCollection and listen to the CollectionEvent (mx.events.CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE)

```
    /**
     *  Dispatched when the ICollectionView has been updated in some way.
     *
     *  @eventType mx.events.CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE
     *  
     *  @langversion 3.0
     *  @playerversion Flash 9
     *  @playerversion AIR 1.1
     *  @productversion Flex 3
     */
    [Event(name="collectionChange", type="mx.events.CollectionEvent")]
```

Comment: I haven't seen this before, I'm using Flash Develop with Flash & Flex SDK but cant seem to import these classes?

Comment: davivid , ArrayCollection is part of the Flex frameworks, which might the reason you can't import them (they're in flex.swc, but not sounds like you're working on a pure as3 project)

Comment: You're right, sorry, did not realized that you're in a pure as3 environment